# How to save current Vim structural configuration across sessions?

Tags: vim, plugins, text-editor

By 'structural configuration' I mean the current open buffers, tabs, windows, and their positions.

By 'across sessions' means that I want to be able to type `:save`, have it save to `~/.vimsconf`, and have typing `:load` actually load those buffers and set up the windows and tabs as they were before, for example.

Is there maybe built in functionality for that? Or maybe a plugin?

I'm using openSUSE 12.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:mks foo.vim` to save the session in file. and

```
vim -S foo.vim
```

will load the session file

check

```
:h :mks
:h views-sessions
```

for detail

Answer (score 2):

You should check `:help session` from within Vim. It explains how it works.